Why Does the /tags Endpoint in the Instagram API Return an IGApiException?
We are using the Instagram API via the Instagram Login feature. We obtained the necessary scopes and have set the app to live status.
Some users of this app can successfully retrieve their tagged media data by calling https://graph.instagram.com/{instagram_account.id}/tags, while others receive the following response:
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported request - method type: get","type":"IGApiException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AJeSMqmb-9xrcVdqxJ9xf3L"}}

Both users are not tester accounts, so it doesn’t seem related to tester settings. Both instagram users are professional account. In other words, some users can fetch the data but others cannot.
Please provide your thoughts on what might be causing this issue. Even after issuing a new access token, the same result occurs. According to the Access Token Debugger, both tokens are valid and have the same permissions.
